# Select no longer highlighting text on iPad (word)

Tags: ipad, office-js

In my add-in we navigate the document by calling select on either a paragraph or a search result from inside a paragraph.  In the newest version of Word for iOS : 2.0.2 (170415)  the document is scrolling to the correct part of the document but the text is no longer highlighting. This was working in the previous released version of word.

Oddly the text does highlight as expected if i open the search bar, and then navigate around my document.

```
  public SelectTextInstance(text: string, paragraphIndex: number, textInstance: number) {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        // Create a proxy object for the paragraphs collection.
        var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;

        context.load(paragraphs, 'text,font');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            if (paragraphIndex == -1) {//currently would occur for items that are inside of tables.
                return;
            }

            var paragraph = paragraphs.items[paragraphIndex];

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                var ranges = null;
                //256 is the maximum length for a search item.  Longer than this and we just have to select the paragraph.
                if (text != undefined && text != null && text.length <= 256) {
                    ranges = paragraph.search(text, { matchCase: true, ignoreSpace: true});
                    context.load(ranges, 'text');
                }
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    if (ranges == null || ranges.items.length == 0) {
                        paragraph.select();
                    }
                    else {
                        //select the paragraph rather than overflow - something bad happened somewhere, so we'll fall back to highlighting the paragraph.
                        if (ranges.items.length <= textInstance) {
                            paragraph.select();
                        } else {
                            ranges.items[textInstance].select();
                        }
                    }
                    return context.sync().then(function () {

                    });

                });
            });
        });
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Since it was working before, it sounds like a bug but could you add the code you're using?

Comment: i am assuming you are using something along the lines of range.select();, right?

Comment: Yes.  I've added my code here for you to take a look.  Again this works perfectly on Mac, Office Online, Word 2016, and it did work perfectly on the ipad previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for reporting this. Effectively this is a regression. The range is selected but not colored. We will push the fix for the next update.

Comment: Awesome glad to hear it.  This won't cause me to fail my validation testing will it?  I resubmitted my app last Thursday.

Comment: it should not affect your add-in submission

Comment: We've had several updates since this was reported and it's still not fixed.  Any idea when we can expect it to be resolved?

Comment: this issue is on the team backlog as of  now.

Comment: update: fixed! will be included in the August update for iOS. Sorry for the delay. Please try it by then and let me know the outcome.

Comment: The August update just came out and unfortunately this is still not working correctly.  I expected it to just light up and begin working but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Is there some way that i can try these updates before they get released?  you said to try it by then but i'm not sure i know of a way to test a pre release ipad for word.

Comment: Hello we just test this on the 2.4.17081002 jsut shipped on Aug 14th and its fixed. Can you please update your app on iOS and check it ?btw you can get the bits earlier using our insider program check this page: https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider?tab=Windows-Desktop

Comment: When you say update my app, you mean publish an update to my web component or do i need to rev the version?  I was thinking that as soon as the update to Word rolled out then it should have been resolved.

Script lab isn't available on ipad, but could you paste some working sample code so that i can compare it to what i am doing.  I validated my version matches and i am not seeing it fixed.

Comment: i mean updating your Word app in your iPad, we recently shipped an update (Aug 14th) that has a fix for this. I am referring to the version number on my last comment, please see if they match.

Comment: Correct, i have that version.  2.4 (170810)

My code to select is fairly simple.  Grab a paragraph object, then execute a search, then grab a particular instance of that.   

                    var ranges = paragraph.search(text, { matchCase: true });
                    context.load(ranges, 'text');
                    return context.sync().then(function () {
                        var selectNum = textInstance;
                        ranges.items[selectNum].select();

Comment: Ok, i figured out what has happened here.

Comment: If you do not have a cursor in the document.  Meaning open a doc, and then immediately do a select from your add in, the bug is still there.  The selection will not be painted.  If you put the cursor in the document first, and then do it then it displays properly.  However there is a new bug where the keyboard then hides and displays after every select call.  I'm going to create a video that shows the bad behavior for you so you can see what i'm talking about

Comment: Here is a link to a video that shows what i'm talking about.  [link](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Aj6T4IiRclkrlcU9-Y-UT8LL_x4GOg)

Comment: Ok thanks for reporting, we can repro an will fix it soon. Sorry

Comment: btw in the meantime you can try to highlight the text (using range.font.highlightColor) ?

Comment: That wouldn't work for me as it would leave the highlights in the document.  Attempting to clear them as i went would be a ton of work and error prone.  My app is a review tool, so we want to avoid making any changes to the document, but i appreciate the suggestion.