# Office JS getSelectedDataAsync find parent of current selection

Tags: office-js

Using Office JS, I can get the current selection using getSelectedDataAsync() , but I'm trying to find the parents and ancestors of my selection, to identify whether or not the selection is inside a table cell or paragraph.

Is there a way to do this?
If (Selection is in TableCell)
    DoThis
Else
    DoThat

Thanks everyone for your help, here is the updated code to get this to work:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    context.load(range);
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        var parentTableCell = range.parentTableCellOrNullObject;
        context.load(parentTableCell);
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            if (parentTableCell.isNullObject)
                console.log("Not in a table cell");
            else
                console.log("In a table cell");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a bit more detail to Stewart's answer: yes, please use document.getSelection to get the range of the selection and from there currently you can get:

1. parentBody - useful if you have multiple sections in the document.
2. parentContentControl - find out if the selection is within a content control
3. parentTable
4. parentTableCell

to find out what's contained within the selection, use the collections:

1. paragraphs,
2. contentControls,
3. Tables,
4. inlinePictures,
5. lists,

etc.
check out the help here
[Select no longer highlighting text on iPad (word)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613951/select-no-longer-highlighting-text-on-ipad-word)

check out this example on how to access a table cell.
Note that in this example if the selection is not within a table cell this will throw an exception. if you want to verify you need to use parentTableCellOrNullObject flavor of the method.. the you can check if nullObject was returned (meaning the selection is not within a table)

```js
   Word.run(function (context) {
        context.document.getSelection().parentTableCell.body.insertText("Hello World","end")
        return context.sync()
     })
```

thanks!

Comment: parentTableCell looks like this is what I am after, is not available in my solution, is that in WordApi 1.1, I google it and can't find it anywhere, the only references I can find to parentTableCell are in oneNote web... Do you have a code sample to share by any chance? Much appreciated

Comment: That's in Word 1.3

Comment: just added a sample so you can see how to access the table cell object.

Answer (score 1):

So in word, there is a method on the Document object called getSelection which returns a range.

Ranges contain a paragraph collection and a table collection.  Depending on which if these are filled should give you your answer.